# Flutter/Dart: The argument type 'bool Function(MyStateNotifier)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'

Tags: flutter, generics, parameters, parameter-passing, typedef

I have a such class declaration in Dart, but when using it the compiler reports error

```dart
typedef ContextConditionFilter<T, bool> = bool Function(T);

class ContextStateWidget<T extends StateNotifier> extends StatefulWidget
{
    final Widget child;
    final ContextConditionFilter<T, bool> filter;
    const ContextStateWidget({Key key, @required this.child, @required this.filter}) : super(key: key);
}
```

A class inherited `StateNotifier`

```dart
class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<DrawMenuState>
{
...
bool get myValue => return true;
}
```

Using it

```dart
ContextStateWidget<MyStateNotifier>(
    filter: ((MyStateNotifier notifier) => notifier.myValue), // error here
    child: const OtherWidget()
);
```

Error

```
The argument type 'bool Function(MyStateNotifier)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)'
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thank [aligator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10533389/aligator) for your reply, but actually it's analyzer problem. After restart VSCode, the problem gone :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 main problems with your code:

1. You should name the input of the function, for example something like `notifier`.

```dart
typedef ContextConditionFilter<T, V> = V Function(T notifier);
```

2. You don't need `return` when using `=>` when defining a function:

```dart
class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<DrawMenuState> {
   bool get myValue => true;
}
```

Everything else should work if you fix these problems.

You also don't need parentheses around your notifier function.

```dart
ContextStateWidget<MyStateNotifier>(
    filter: (MyStateNotifier notifier) => notifier.myValue,
    child: const OtherWidget(),
);
```